# How does instantiation of higher-rank types and subsumption interact during unification?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, polymorphism, unification, higher-rank-types

A function type is higher-rank if a quantifier appears in contravariant position: `f :: (forall a. [a] -> b) -> Bool`

Regarding the unification of such a type the type variable `a` is more rigid than `b`, because the following instantiation rules apply:

- `a` can be instantiated with a flexible type variable, provided this doesn't allow `a` to escape its scope
- or with another rigid type variable
- but not with a non-abstract type, because not the caller of `foo` but `foo` itself decides what `a` is, while `b` is already determined by the caller

However, things get more complicated as soon as subsumption comes into play:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

f :: (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Int -- rank-2
f _ = undefined

arg1a :: a -> a
arg1a x = x

arg1b :: [Int] -> [Int]
arg1b x = x

f arg1a -- type checks
f arg1b -- rejected

g :: ((forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Int) -> Int -- rank-3
g _ = undefined

arg2a :: (a -> a) -> Int
arg2a _ = 1

arg2b :: (forall a. a -> a) -> Int
arg2b _ = 1

arg2c :: ([Int] -> [Int]) -> Int
arg2c _ = 1

g arg2a -- type checks
g arg2b -- rejected
g arg2c -- type checks

h :: (((forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Int) -> Int) -> Int -- rank-4
h _ = undefined

arg3a :: ((a -> a) -> Int) -> Int
arg3a _ = 1

arg3b :: ((forall a. a -> a) -> Int) -> Int
arg3b _ = 1

arg3c :: (([Int] -> [Int]) -> Int) -> Int
arg3c _ = 1

h arg3a -- rejected
h arg3b -- type checks
h arg3c -- rejected
```

What immediately catches the eye is the subtype relation, which gets flipped for each additional contravariant position. The application `g arg2b` is rejected, because `(forall a. a -> a)` is more polymorphic than `(forall a. [a] -> [a])` and thus `(forall a. a -> a) -> Int` is less polymorphic than `(forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Int`.

The first thing I don't understand is why `g arg2a` is accepted. Does subsumption only kick in if both terms are higher-rank?

However, the fact that `g arg2c` type checks puzzles me even more. Doesn't this clearly violate the rule that the rigid type variable `a` must not be instantiated with a monotype like `Int`?

Maybe someone can lay out the unification process for both applications..

Comment: If `arg2c` can accept an `[Int] -> [Int]` function as its first argument, then it can certainly accept the `forall a. [a] -> [a]` function that `g` is going to give to it, simply by subsequently choosing `a ~ Int`. (This should give a high-level intuition, but doesn't get into the details of unification that you're asking for, so not really an answer.)

Comment: Roughly put, a doubly-contravariant position is a covariant position since the "double negative" cancels out, which can also be seen as a consequence of the subtype relation being flipped twice. Indeed, in your `g arg2c` the type `a` can be instantiated as `Int`, since if we compute the needed subtype checks, we end up with `([Int] -> [Int]) -> Int <: (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Int` and then, flipping the relation, with `forall a. [a] -> [a] <: [Int] -> [Int]` which follows by instantiation.

Comment: @chi I get the relation `forall a. [a] -> [a] <: [Int] -> [Int]`, but the quantifier is still hanging around. However, now it isn't in contravariant position anymore, right? If `a` isn't rank-1+n but rank-1 after the subtype checks, than `a` can be instantiated with `Int`, of course, because `a` is a flexible type variable that can be instantiated with a type constant. So simply put, the process of subtype checks changes the nesting and thus the rank of the involved quantifiers. Is this about right?

Comment: @scriptum Yes in the last `<:` the forall is at the top-level, so it's covariant. In the process the rank changes since we move from a larger type to its components. IMO, thinking about the rank does not help much understanding this. The last `<:` is simply a case of the general rule `(forall a.T) <: T{U/a}` where `{U/a}` denotes the substitution of type variable `a` with type `U`. This rule and `(a->b) <: (a'->b')   iff   b<:b' and a'<:a` is all you need for type checking your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

```
g :: ((forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Int) -> Int
arg2c :: ([Int] -> [Int]) -> Int
```

which are applied in `g arg2c`.

To type check this, it suffices to verify that the type of the argument is a subtype of the function domain type. I.e. that we have

```
([Int] -> [Int]) -> Int <: ((forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Int)
```

According to the subtyping rules, we have `(a->b) <: (a'->b')` if and only if `b<:b'` and `a'<:a`. So the above is equivalent to

```
Int <: Int
forall a. [a] -> [a] <: [Int] -> [Int]
```

The first inequality is trivial. The second one holds because a `foall` type is a subtype of each one if its instances. Formally, `(forall a. T) <: T{U/a}` where `{U/a}` denotes the substitution of type variable `a` with type `U`.  Hence,

```
forall a. [a] -> [a] <: ([a] -> [a]){Int/a} = [Int] -> [Int]
```